# How to pass parameter with action using Ember.Button?

Tags: ember.js

In the Ember.js app that I'm working on, I want to pass the parameter from template to controller function but can not.

**Template**

```
{{#view Ember.Button target="MyApp.Controller" action="start"}}

{{/view}}
```

**Controller**

```
App.MyAppClass = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        start: function(arg) {
            console.log(arg);
        }
    }
});
```

Are there anyone used to meet this problem?

Comment: What parameter are you trying to send?  It's not possible to give you a proper answer without seeing what it is you're trying to send.

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that you are referencing the right controller?

I just did a quick mock test with -

```
/** templates/foobar.hbs **/
<button {{action "foo" "bar"}}>Foobar</button>

/** controllers/foobar.js **/
var FoobarController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
       foo: function (args) {
           alert(args); // getting an alert with "bar"
       },
    }
});
```

I suggest reading - 
http://emberjs.com/guides/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/

```
{{#view Ember.Button target="MyApp.Controller" action="start" param="parameter"}}

{{/view}}
```

Comment: if I use <button {{action "foo" "bar"}}>Foobar</button> it work. but {{#view Ember.Button target="MyApp.Controller" action="start" param="parameter"}} it doesn't work.

Comment: I think its your target that is causing a problem. Try "App.MyAppClass" or "MyAppClass"